# jQuery Validation plugin always shows error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, jquery-plugins

I create custom validation for email checking in the DB.

Client:

```
Template.Login.onRendered(() => {
  jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkEmailUnique', function(value, element) {
    Meteor.call('checkEmailUnique', value, function(err, result) {
      console.log('Email validator method response: ', result);
      return result;
    )};
  });

  $('.login-form').validate({
  rules: {
      emailAddress: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        checkEmailUnique: true
      },
  messages: {
     checkEmailUnique: "email found"
      }
  });
});
```

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  // Chech the email to unique
  checkEmailUnique:function(email){
     if(email && Meteor.isServer){
       let foundEmail = Meteor.users.findOne({'emails.address': email});
       if (foundEmail) {
         return false; // fails - display error
       } else {
         return true; // true - no message
       }
     }
  }
});
```

In the browser console I get message:

if email found - false and if email not found - true, but plugin in both cases chow my validation message "email found".

What am I doing wrong?

**Update.**

So, after the first answer I change code to:

```
Template.Login.onRendered(() => {
  jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkEmailUnique', function(value, element) {
    return Meteor.wrapAsync(Meteor.call)('checkEmailUnique', value, element);
  });
});
```

In both cases I get validation message that email is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is returning asynchronously so the return value is not getting passed back to the validator. You need to wrap your `Meteor.call()` with `Meteor.wrapAsync()` in order to use it synchronously.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkEmailUnique', function(value, element) {
  return Meteor.wrapAsync(Meteor.call)('checkEmailUnique', value);
});
```

If you think your `Meteor.call()` might error then a try-catch block is necessary because `Meteor.wrapAsync()` is returning the result but not the error:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkEmailUnique', function(value, element) {
  try {
    return Meteor.wrapAsync(Meteor.call)('checkEmailUnique', value);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e); // handle the error as required
  }
});
```

Comment: If I use this way with wrong email I don't get validation message.

Comment: What is `Meteor.wrapAsync(Meteor.call('checkEmailUnique', value))` returning?

Comment: I don't known how to look return value.

Comment: `Meteor.wrapAsync` expects a function, not the result of `Meteor.call`, that is `undefined`

Comment: @MichelFloyd I think you meant `Meteor.wrapAsync(Meteor.call)('checkEmailUnique', value)`

Comment: @MichelFloyd I create screen with checkEmailUnique responce. https://ibb.co/hxYkYk

Comment: This version in both cases show my validation message "email found".